# Deploy Symfony 2.7 on shared hosting without SSH

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, shared-hosting

Good day friends,
I know that similar questions exist for deploying a Symfony 2.7 application on shared hosting with CPanel. But in my case I do not have access to SSH. Therefore installing via Composer is out of question.

To work around it I have copied the entire sources into a sub folder in "public_html" folder. When I try to configure Symfony using "web/config.php" it gives some pre-requisites issues. To resolve this I have copied custom "php.ini" in my sub folder and also added the ".htaccess" file to root of "home/user" with following content

```
SetEnv PHPRC /home/user/public_html/subfolder/php.ini
```

But still the setting is not taking affect. Do i need to ask the hosting provider to restart the web server ? this wont be easy since it is shared hosting.

Please suggest any alternative way

Comment: Try `RewriteBase /subfolder/web/` in your .htaccess

Comment: Added the lines below lines, but my custom php.ini is not taking affect 
`RewriteBase /subfolder/web/`
`SetEnv PHPRC /home/user/public_html/subfolder/php.ini`

Comment: I was still adding my comment but enter was considered as sending the message

Comment: You can move the `.htaccess` into the `public_html/` folder, you do not need the custom php.ini to deploy a symfony app to my knowledge, but the `.htaccess` currently does not get addressed since it is outside the `public_html` folder. So first move it and then see if the config works (and perhaps your `php.ini`), please

Comment: I have moved the `.htaccess` file into the "public_html" folder but still no affect. You are saying that I do not need custom `php.ini`, well Symfony is saying I need to set `mbstring.func_overload` to zero (0) I have tried both in `php.ini` and `parameters.yml` like `mbstring.func_overload: 0` but no affect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104460/discussion-between-ciccio-and-saqib-mustafa-abbasi).

Answer (score 0):

Your custom `.htaccess` is not used by the application.

Try to add the `SetEnv` in the `public_html/web/.htaccess` that is used to browse your application.

If this has no effect, a working way is to add the following in the `VirtualHost` of your application:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    PHPINIDir /home/user/public_html/subfolder/php.ini
</VirtualHost>
```

But that involves to restart apache once.

**EDIT**

If PHP run as CGI:

Create a wrapper script called phpini.cgi to export the directory that **contains** the php.ini file as PHPRC.

```
#!/bin/sh
export PHPRC=/home/user/public_html/subfolder
exec /path/to/cgi-bin/php5.cgi
```

In your `/home/user/public_html/web/.htaccess` add the following lines:

```
AddHandler php-cgi .php
Action php-cgi /cgi-bin/phpini.cgi
```

If php run as CGI with wrapper (for FASTCGI):

You should already have the following wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=3
exec /path/to/cgi-bin/php5.cgi
```

Change it to:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=3
exec /path/to/cgi-bin/php.cgi -c /home/user/public_html/subfolder/php.ini
```

More informations and alternatives in the [source](http://www.askapache.com/php/custom-phpini-tips-and-tricks.html).

I hope this solves your problem, it should if you are sure you are php run as cgi/fast-cgi.

Comment: I have moved the `.htaccess` file into the web folder but still no affect, also please note that I cannot restart the server so the virtualhost option is not valid. :(

Comment: It seems the `SetEnv PHPRC` has definitively no effect. Do you know if you are using php as apache module or by CGI/FastCGI SAPI ?

Comment: Need to confirm with my hosting provider, but it has to be Apache because if i added a error command inside the `.htaccess` file site doesnt work

Comment: I hope it works too, but I have a question, will I be able to do all the above even if I have access to only `/home/user` through FTP and nothing else

Comment: That will depends on the location of the `php-cgi` directory. If it's in your `home`, you are good, otherwise, I don't know what say you :/

Comment: in that case i'm stuck, let me talk to my hosting provider tomorrow then i will see what can be done

Comment: @Saqib I had one more addition (Not sure if you read that in the chat), when you get this working: Make sure to protect your installation, as all your files are accessible from public now. You can check this in the [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-web-directory), to make only the web directory public. (For example, move your installation back to `/home/user/` and change the settings according the cookbook instructions. But, of course, you will need to tackle the CGI/FastCGI obstacle first.. Good luck!

Comment: Yes I read that but was waiting to get something up before experimenting with the paths, thanks